# Trying to understand polymorphic classes with the use of std::function with different method signatures

Tags: polymorphism, std-function

I'm fairly new, and am trying to come up with an example to help me understand polymorphism, type-erasure, and the use of std::function.

I am trying to understand by creating this example class, which can take in a base value, and then a std::function which then one of many math operations on the base value.

```
double multiplyValue(double baseVal, double multiplyBy) {
    return baseVal * multiplyBy;
}

double divideValue(double baseVal, double divideBy) {
    return baseVal / divideBy;
}

double subtractFromDividedValue(double baseVal, double subtract, double divideBy) {
    return subtract - (baseVal / divideBy);
}

double inverseSubtract(double baseVal, double subtract) {
    return -(baseVal - subtract);
}

class PrintValue
{
public:
    PrintValue(int baseVal, std::function<double(double, double)> modifierFunc) {
        this->baseVal = baseVal;
        this->modifierFunc = modifierFunc;
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << "Value : " << modifierFunc(baseVal, 2) << "\n";
    }

private:
    int baseVal;
    std::function<double(double, double)> modifierFunc;
};

int main()
{
    PrintValue multiplyVal(2, multiplyValue);
    multiplyVal.print(); 

    PrintValue divideVal(2, divideValue);
    divideVal.print();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My PrintVal class works multiplyValue divideValue, and inverseSubtract because they have the same method signatures -- but when I want my "PrintValue" class to be able to accept the subtractFromDividedValue function...this is where I get confused!

Also, I notice I've hard-coded "2" as the method argument being passed into modifierFunc in the print() function.

I'd like to be able to dynamically pass in a variable amount of method arguments into the class as well, but am confused here because the subtractFromDividedValue has more parameters than the other math functions.  So I think I just need to make an interface, and overload the class for all the possible argument permutations, is that correct?

Ultimately I just want a class that I can pass a function into that dynamically modifies the "baseValue"...

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I think I just need to make an interface, and overload the class for all the possible argument permutations, is that correct?

There are lots of ways you could do it, best is to try things and see how they pan out - create a new question here if think something is promising but you get stuck.  As an example of one approach, you could make your printer work in terms of a `baseVal` to modify, a variable number of parameters provided using a `vector`, and a function to apply the transformation...

```
PrintValue(double baseVal, std::vector<double> otherParameters, std::function<double(double, std::vector<double>)> modifierFunc)
  : baseVal_{baseVal}, otherParams_{std::move(otherParameters)}
{ }
```

...you could create suitable functions like...

```
double subtractFromDividedValue(double baseVal, const std::vector<double>& params) {
    double subtract = params.at(0), divideBy = params.at(1);
    return subtract - (baseVal / divideBy);
}
```

For more flexibility you could let parameters be added when calling `print`:

```
void print(const std::vector<double>& extraParams) {
    if (extraParams.size())
    {
        std::vector<double> allParams{ otherParams_.begin(), otherParams_.end() };
        for (double p : extraParams) 
            allParams.push_back(p);
        std::cout << "Value : " << modifierFunc(baseVal, allParams) << "\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Value : " << modifierFunc(baseVal, otherParams_) << "\n";
}
```